# How to filter a key in a Map with only 3 string length?

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have the LinkHashMap here.

```
Map<String, String> map

{011A=HongKong, 012B=London, 015Y=NewYork, 312=China, 272=Canada}
```

I would like to filter or arrange the map to be this,

Only the key with a 3 digit or length = 3 kept in the map.

```
{312=China, 272=Canada}
```

What kind of method could I use?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `map.keySet().removeIf(k -> k.length() != 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 (or higher) there is a convenient feature called Lambda that provides a nice api to work with streams.

**To create a second map with only the filtered keys use this below code:**

```
Map<String, String> originMap;
Map<String, String> filteredmap = originMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getKey().length() == 3)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

**If you want to remove the elements from your map itself :**

```
Map<String, String> map;
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getKey().length != 3);
```

Comment: No need to remove from the entry set, just from the key set is enough

Comment: I didn't knew that, but i feel like removing from the entrySet is more explicit in the intention.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

```
Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        String s = it.next();
        if(s.length() != 3){
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method like this to filter,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("011A", "HongKong");
            put("012B", "London");
            put("015Y", "NewYork");
            put("312", "China");
            put("272", "Canada");
        }};

        Map<String, String> filteredMap = filterMap(map);
    }

    static Map<String, String> filterMap (Map<String, String> map) {
        HashMap<String, String> filteredMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key: map.keySet()) {
            if (key.length() == 3) {
                filteredMap.put(key, map.get(key));
            }
        }
        return filteredMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat what are you trying to say?

Comment: @GhostCat I didn't get you. Can you explain how did you find it funny?

Comment: Well. The fact that there is a single comment answering the question ... and that minutes later, you drop quite a bit of code (without much of explanations) ... basically: that looks a bit odd. In the "not exactly a great answer" area. But you wrote that code, so no reason to downvote the answer. But also few people will upvote such input. Thus "funny". But I agree, my wording isnt obvious ...

Comment: @GhostCat So the single line code gives the explanation? And my one doesn't? True. It might not be the best answer. No issues with that. Is there are time limit to answer in here? And I wanted to see if it works. Since I'm not expert. That took me some time. But the issue is I still didn't get what you find funny here. Can you explain a bit more? And where is your first comment? Why did you delete it?

Comment: @GhostCat Which part do you want me to explain in my code? I written it with meaningful names and if you read it from top to bottom you should clearly see what I did there. But still I can explain to you if you don't get it :) After you answer my questions tho :)

Answer (score 0):

**For Java >= 8:**

```
public static Map<String, String> filterMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().length() == 3)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

**For Java < 8:**

```
public static Map<String, String> filterMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
        if (entry.getKey().length() == 3)
            res.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

    return res;
}
```